# AJAX calls are getting null values after some repetitive same requests every second

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have an requirement to get data repetitively from DB and update in page.
So i have used Jquery ajax api call and it will make a request for every second and update the values in page.

But after some repetitive api requests(may be up to 60  to 70) no more requests are happening and even site loading takes 5 to 10 minutes.

Does any one have ideas?

```js
var interval = 1000; // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds

function GetVehicleInfo() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/Dashboard/GetCustomerVehicleDetails',
    async: true,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      resultModel = data[0];
      ko.applyBindings(resultModel);
    },
    error: function() {},
    complete: function(data) {
      setTimeout(GetVehicleInfo, interval);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  resultModel = {};
  setTimeout(GetVehicleInfo, interval);
});
```

Comment: You are DDOS-ing yourself. Don't use AJAX polling, it's an anti-pattern for this very reason. If you need to keep the UI and server side data in sync, use Web Sockets or Server Sent Events

Comment: You can use `SignalR` for this sort of things. [Getting Started with SignalR 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Comment: Thanks adiga for suggestion and I implemented  with signalR and resolved my issue